# Hot reload using EAS

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

1. About a year ago, when I was using Expo to build react native apps, there were :-

- hot reload
- hosting to Expo build site, from where testers could download by scanning the QR code
- run time errors display on emulator or connected device

2. When I revisited the app after a break of 1 year, I see that Expo is migrating to EAS (Expo Application Services). So, I ejected from Expo, and use 'eas build' .
3. Now I build using 'preview' profile, download the '.apk' from the EAS build site, drag it onto Android Emulator to test.
4. However, I don't see the above facilities of 'hot reload' and 'uploading to an Expo site for testers to download', or 'run time errors display on connected device'.
5. What is the alternative ? Should I go back to using react-native build ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It a little easier to answer your question if there is only one question

> However, I don't see the above facilities of 'hot reload' ..

Shaking the device should show a fast refresh option

[image: fast refresh]

> ..and 'uploading to an Expo site for testers to download'

You can use EAS updates together with the [dev-client](https://docs.expo.dev/eas-update/expo-dev-client/)

```
eas update --branch testers --message "Feature A"
```

1. Shake device
2. "Go home"
3. Extensions
4. sign in (to an expo user that is connected to an organisation)
5. pick the updates to try out

> or 'run time errors display on connected device'.

It should display the errors (it does that for me with the dev-client)

> What is the alternative ? Should I go back to using react-native build ?

There aren't many great alternative to expo - perhaps "vanilla" React Native with some [firebase features](https://rnfirebase.io/) or [Microsoft app center](https://appcenter.ms/)?

Hope this answer your question(s).